# How do I use my secondary GPU for display output and primary only for computation?

Tags: xorg, nvidia, display, gpu

I have two GPU's, GTX 1070 and GT 710. I have only one display and I would like this display to run off of the GT710 so that I can continue to work when I am training models using CUDA. I have been at this for quite a few hours and the furthest I have been able to get is to boot into Mint in "fallback mode" with the monitor connected to the GT 710.

I have been following the instructions here:
https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/how-do-i-set-one-gpu-for-display-and-the-other-two-gpus-for-cuda-computing/49113

My system information is as follows

[image]

I have tried two methods

1)First Attempt: As suggested by user "birdie" the link above, I created the file nvidia.conf in directory /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d, with the following content

```
    Section "Device"
        Identifier      "GT710"
        BusID           "PCI:5:0:0" # my Bus ID for gt710
        Driver          "nvidia"
        VendorName      "NVIDIA"
    EndSection
```

Then I went to xorg.conf in /etc/X11/ and modified the entry for screen as follows

```
Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "GT710" #modified here
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-6"
    Option         "metamodes" "2560x1440_75 +0+0"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

By doing this I was able to boot into mint in fallback mode with my display connected to the GT710.

2)Second Attempt: I created a second device entry in /etc/X11/xorg.conf

```
    Section "Device"
        Identifier     "Device1"
        Driver         "nvidia"
        VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
        BusID           "PCI:5:0:0" 
        BoardName      "GeForce GT 710"
        option          "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration"                    
    EndSection
```

Then I edited the Screen entry in /etc/X11/xorg.conf as follows:

```
Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device1" #edited here
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-6"
    Option         "metamodes" "2560x1440_75 +0+0"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Again I was able to boot into mint but only in fallback mode when connected to the GT710.

I would appreciate any help in making this work.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. The solution is to use approach #2 and edit /etc/X11/xorg.conf/ to add second GPU as shown above. Then under Section "screen" change "MultiGPU" to "on"

more details can be seen here[enter link description here](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/how-do-i-set-one-gpu-for-display-and-the-other-two-gpus-for-cuda-computing/49113/16)

I will post my new xorg.con in case it helps anyone in the future

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 440.82

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
    EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load           "dbe"
    Load           "extmod"
    Load           "type1"
    Load           "freetype"
    Load           "glx"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Philips PHL 325E1"
    HorizSync       114.0 - 114.0
    VertRefresh     48.0 - 75.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

#makes gtx 1070 work on display

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 1070"
EndSection

#added to make GT710 run my Display doesnt work
Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
BusID           "PCI:5:0:0"
option          "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration"                    
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device1"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-6"
    Option         "metamodes" "2560x1440_75 +0+0"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "on" #"Off" #CHANGE APPLIED HERE
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```